# Passing params to Stored Procedure-Special case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SaveUserCustomerXRef]
    @Username varchar(48),
    @LinkID varchar(48)
AS
DELETE FROM UserCustomerX WHERE UserName=@UserName AND LinkID=@LID
INSERT INTO UserCustomerX(Username, LID)
VALUES (@Username, @LID)
```

is executed As-

1. EXEC usp_SaveUserCustomerXRef '10026:ttmm19',2H0;//Syntax error
2. EXEC usp_SaveUserCustomerXRef '10026:ttmm19',A1;//Executed+Inserted
3. EXEC usp_SaveUserCustomerXRef '10026:ttmm19',2;//Executed+Inserted
4. EXEC usp_SaveUserCustomerXRef '10026:ttmm19','2H0';//Executed+Inserted

   The columns in the table UserCustomerX  are of type Varchar.My problem is with case no:2 why does it insert values though there is no single quotes.But Case No:1 gave syntax error.Case 3&4 are normal conditions. Why does case 2 work? without quotes?

Comment: My guess is that it is because #1 begins with a number and #2 does not - implicit conversion?

Comment: Yes that's what it looks like.... @Nicarus... I think you can add it as an answer..

Comment: is there something has to do with Hexadecimal Numbers? Like A1 ?

Comment: You could always test your theories rather simply - instead of inserting A1, use Z1 (not a hexadecimal) and see what happens. If you just experiment with it a little, I think you will find your own answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second paramter @LinkID  is a varchar, so you better force and generalize the use of quotes when executing your stored procedure.

And as Nicarus said, it's probably an implicit conversion to number which provoke the syntax error.